# Take the cell values more than one from ".CSV" to Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have . csv table in below;

```
name;location;id;number
space;usa;123;110001
sky;canada;124;110002
plane;peru;126;1100011
cloud;italy;127;1111033
```

I want to reach the in 'name' column cell values for example 'space' cell in csv file , if it finds the 'space' after the I want to take its the location and/or id value in same ".csv" file by Powershell.

I used for `$A = Import-Csv -Path`code for take the .csv file. But I can not reach the name columnn or any cell as clearly.
`$A.name` or `$A.location` is not working in powershell I tried.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by location? You would like to find the array index number for specific value in column Name? If that is so $a.name.IndexOf('space') will return the index number of value space. Be aware it is case sensitive!

Comment: @Ivan Mirchev I want to reach same line cell with 'name' and 'location'. For example the cell valur is 'sky', I want to 'sky' cell's location valur so I want to find 'canada' cell.

Comment: please refer to the provided answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative, if I am understanding the request correctly. 
If you would like to find the row with the name `sky`, then:

**Note**: test.csv contains the provided input.

```
Import-Csv -Path .\test.csv -Delimiter ';' | Where-Object -Property Name -eq 'sky'

name location id  number
---- -------- --  ------
sky  canada   124 110002
```

this would return all the rows with `Name` equal to `sky`.
Of course you may use the operator `-like` so to utilize the wildcard, i.e.

```
Import-Csv -Path .\test.csv -Delimiter ';' | Where-Object -Property Name -like 's*'

name  location id  number
----  -------- --  ------
space usa      123 110001
sky   canada   124 110002
```

This would return all the names starting with letter `s`.

If you need only the location, then you may use `Select-Object`

```
Import-Csv -Path .\test.csv -Delimiter ';' | Where-Object -Property Name -eq 'sky' | Select-Object -Property Location

location
--------
canada
```

Or address the property directly:

```
(Import-Csv -Path .\test.csv -Delimiter ';' | Where-Object -Property Name -eq 'sky').Location

canada
```

Or:

```
$result = Import-Csv -Path .\test.csv -Delimiter ';' | Where-Object -Property Name -eq 'sky'
$result.location

canada
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell imports CSV files with a comma (,) as the delimiter by default. To import a file where a semicolon is the delimiter you need to use the delimiter switch:

```
$test = import-csv .\stackoverflowtest.csv -Delimiter ';'
```

You can then address each line in your CSV like so:

```
$test[n].name
```

Where n is the current number you want to access, starting with a 0.